# Regarding Null Pointer exception android

Tags: android

I have done an android app which has custom database file in the external memory  when I am using my app  its working fine but after a  day, it is returning `null pointer exception`.

Then I read some articles, in that problem because of database  connection. android_os closes a connection after certain time.

now the question is how can make db available for app lifetime(long time). suggest me to to reopen db file if db got closed.

Comment: Post the logcat of the error.

Comment: hello Tuga, thanks for response. problem is coming only when  app trying to access at very fist time in the next day or after a long time that to when i was trying to do first access.

Comment: Still, you should have the logcat output to debug the error properly.

Comment: Thank you, i resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try checking if your database is open every time you make any sql query. similar to below

```
   getUserData(int id)
   {
        if(db == null || !db.isOpen())
       // re initialize and open db 


         // run your sql query here

   }
```

Comment: i had applied this code but it is retuning null pointer exception at where ever we wrote  this line..

Comment: i am fetching data from custom db file located in external sd card.  when i am try to apply your code in particular activity it say null pointer exception in your code

Comment: code : if(!app.myDbHelper.myDataBase.isOpen() || app.myDbHelper.myDataBase==null)
  {
   Log.d(TAG, "Db is closed");
   app.ReadyApplicationDatabase(SplashScreenActivity.this);
   app.myDbHelper.openDataBase();
   Log.d(TAG, "Db is Re-Opened");
  }
  
  Log.d(TAG, "Db is working fine "+b+"  "+app.myDbHelper.myDataBase.toString());

Comment: 00: E/AndroidRuntime(14057): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 15:26:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(14057): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{/com.aaa.eventsmart.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: paste entire log that will show where is the null pointer exception